# ошибка при использовании React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При попытке использования react router возникает ошибка с хуком useref(), также, добавлю, при попытке использовать библиотеку Swiper - возникает ошибка useState(), раньше не возникала
[image: вот ошибка с хуком useRef]

Comment: И как мы должны вам помочь без кода? Тут нет гадалок)